# In springboot JPA one to one mapping response getting only values

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Code for the controller class which will return response:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ProcessInfo/1.0.0")
public class RestController {
@ApiOperation(value = "getdeployments", notes = "This REST API is used to get deployments")
    @GetMapping(value = "/getdeployments")
    private List<ActivitiProcessDeployment> getdeployments() {

        return ActivitiGetDeploymentRepository.getDeployment();
    }
```

Below are the two entity classes having one to one mapping.

```
 @Entity
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="ActivitiProcessDeployment.getDeployment", query="SELECT a.id,a.name,a.category,a.tenantId,a.deployTime,b.category,b.key,b.resource_name,b.version,b.deploymentId,b.diagramResourceName,b.description,b.id,b.hasStartFormKey,b.hasGraphicalNotation_,b.suspensionState,b.tenant_id_ FROM ActivitiProcessDeployment a INNER JOIN ActivitiProcessDefinition b ON a.id=b.deploymentId ORDER BY a.id")})
@Table(name="act_re_deployment")
public class ActivitiProcessDeployment implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="id_")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="name_")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="category_")
    private String category;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="tenant_id_")
    private String tenantId;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="deploy_time_")
    private Date deployTime;

    @JsonProperty
    @OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="deploymentId", nullable=true)
    private ActivitiProcessDefinition activitiProcessDefinition;
    }
```

Another entity class

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="act_re_procdef")
public class ActivitiProcessDefinition implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("process_def")
    @Id
    @Column(name="id_")
    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="rev_")
    private String rev;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="category_")
    private String category;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="name_")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="key_")
    private String key;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="resource_name_")
    private String resource_name;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="version_")
    private String version;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="deployment_id_")
    private String deploymentId;
    }
```

JPA repository which is extending crud repository and calling the named query which is declared in the entity class.

```
@Repository
public interface ActivitiGetDeploymentRepository extends JpaRepository<ActivitiProcessDeployment, Long> {

    public List<ActivitiProcessDeployment> getDeployment();

}
```

The response I'm getting is:

```
    [
    [
        "1",
        "ExecutionTaskListener",
        null,
        "-1234",
        "2018-10-29T07:31:48.373+0000",
        "http://www.activiti.org/test",
        "myProcess",
        "ExecutionTaskListener.bpmn20.xml",
        "1",
        "1",
        "ExecutionTaskListener.myProcess.png",
        null,
        "myProcess:1:4",
        "f",
        "t",
        "1",
        "-1234"
    ],
    [
        "13",
        "multiinstance (1)",
        null,
        "-1234",
        "2018-10-29T07:31:49.901+0000",
        "http://www.activiti.org/test",
        "multiinstance",
        "multiinstance.bpmn20.xml",
        "1",
        "13",
        "multiinstance.multiinstance.png",
        null,
        "multiinstance:1:16",
        "f",
        "t",
        "1",
        "-1234"
    ],
    [
        "23",
        "testing",
        null,
        "-1234",
        "2018-10-29T07:31:50.591+0000",
        "http://www.activiti.org/test",
        "myProcess",
        "testing.bpmn20.xml",
        "2",
        "23",
        "testing.myProcess.png",
        null,
        "myProcess:2:26",
        "f",
        "t",
        "1",
        "-1234"
    ]
]
```

As shown in the above response I am getting only json values I mean only table values without column names. So, how to get json response mapped with response coresponding key.

Comment: Do you get that response through some controller or how?

Comment: yeah using controller

Comment: Add the code for that also especially where you use and return the data fetched with `getDeployment()`

Comment: I have added the controller class

Comment: Why do you have the named query? To have the result flatten?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do and what actually happens (and why it is even possible). But as you can see your JSON is not a list of `ActivitiProcessDeployment` but a list of string lists.

Your named query does not return `ActivitiProcessDeployment`s but a list of column values. Without any named query and an interface like below:

```
public interface ActivitiGetDeploymentRepository
            extends JpaRepository<ActivitiProcessDeployment, Long> {
    public List<ActivitiProcessDeployment> findAllOrderById();
}
```

you might get better results. It would not be flat as your JSON but `ActivitiProcessDefinition` would be nested inside your `ActivitiProcessDeployment`.

**And** if you need to do projection see this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53239376/6413377) .

Comment: @vikram See my update on another answer to a similar question