# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.entity.MechanicEntity

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jpa, casting

I am getting the following error "Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.entity.MechanicEntity" when trying to fetch the list of mechanic rows from database and pass to the jsp page.

**Mechanic Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Mechanic")
public class MechanicEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

int mechanicId;
String mechanicType;
int numberOfVehicles;
public int getMechanicId() {
    return mechanicId;
}
public void setMechanicId(int mechanicId) {
    this.mechanicId = mechanicId;
}
public String getMechanicType() {
    return mechanicType;
}
public void setMechanicType(String mechanicType) {
    this.mechanicType = mechanicType;
}
public int getNumberOfVehicles() {
    return numberOfVehicles;
}
public void setNumberOfVehicles(int numberOfVehicles) {
    this.numberOfVehicles = numberOfVehicles;
}

}
```

**RegisterController.java**

```
...
RegisterService service;
 @ModelAttribute("MechList")
 public Map<Integer,Integer> populateMechId()throws Exception {

    List<Mechanic> allMech = service.getAllMechanic();
    Map<Integer,Integer> MechanicMap=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

    for(Mechanic mechanic:allMech){
        MechanicMap.put(mechanic.getMechanicId(),mechanic.getMechanicId());
    }

    return MechanicMap;
}  ...
```

**RegisterService.java**

```
...
RegisterDAO dao;
public List<Mechanic> getAllMechanic() throws Exception
{
  return dao.getAllMechanic();
}
...
```

**RegisterDAO.java**

```
public List<Mechanic> getAllMechanic() throws Exception
{
    List<Mechanic> mlist=new ArrayList<Mechanic>();
    Query q=em.createQuery("select m.mechanicId,m.mechanicType from MechanicEntity m");
    List<MechanicEntity> l1=q.getResultList();
    for(MechanicEntity m:l1)
    {
        Mechanic mechanic=new Mechanic();
        mechanic.setMechanicId(m.getMechanicId());
        mlist.add(mechanic);

    }
    return mlist;
}
```

**registerVehicle.jsp**

```
<form:form name="registerForm1"  action="registerVehicle.htm"  modelAttribute="serviceregister" method="GET" >
<form:select path="mechanicId">
<form:options items="${MechList}" />
</form:select>
</form:form>
```

**Error:**

```
Type Exception Report

Message org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.entity.MechanicEntity

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.entity.MechanicEntity
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:594)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:495)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



Root Cause 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.entity.MechanicEntity
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:472)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



Root Cause 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.entity.MechanicEntity
    com.dao.RegisterDAO.getAllMechanic(RegisterDAO.java:19)
    com.service.RegisterService.getAllMechanic(RegisterService.java:27)
    com.controller.RegisterController.populateMechId(RegisterController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:163)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:472)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please help me rectify it, so the dropdown is displayed when the view loads.

Comment: Have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53239376/6413377), maybe it helps you. You are not fetching `MechanicEntity` but some DTO or projection with two fields from `MechanicEntity`.

Comment: Is there any need to have MechanicEntity and Mechanic classes? Only MechanicEntity seems enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't even compile because of:

```
Query q=em.createQuery("select m.mechanicId,m.mechanicType from MechanicEntity m");
List<MechanicEntity> l1=q.getResultList();
```

The problem is that `getResultList()` return a `List<Object>` instead of `List< MechanicEntity>`.

To make it work:

```
 List<MechanicEntity> l1 = createQuery("select m from MechanicEntity m", MechanicEntity.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: I made the changes and now it shows, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [com.entity.MechanicEntity]
"

Comment: @Sidzler See my updated answer. Your query was wrong.